# Why this core dumped is generated

Tags: c, debugging, gdb, coredump

I am writing a C program whose relevant details are below:

```
void calculate(struct iso_matrix *iso_matrix) {
        struct graphlet *graphlet = init_graphlet(GL_SIZE);
        int *index_map = (int *)malloc(iso_matrix->n_rw_col);
        //some other stuff. Working fine.
        free(index_map);    //line 90(for future references)
}
```

The output I get at terminal:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./bin/exec: free(): invalid next size (fast):0x00000000023696f0 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x7eb96)[0x2b3b5fc92b96]
./bin/exec[0x403ff9]
./bin/exec[0x4049eb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x2b3b5fc3576d]
./bin/exec[0x400889]
======= Memory map: ========
(not shown here)
```

And the GDB backtrace is:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7a51425 in raise () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#1  0x00007ffff7a54b8b in abort () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007ffff7a8f39e in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#3  0x00007ffff7a99b96 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
#4  0x0000000000403ff9 in calculate (iso_matrix=0x6084a0) at src/graphlet_iso_mat.c:90
#5  0x00000000004049eb in main (argc=3, argv=0x7fffffffdef8) at src/main.c:70
```

I am unable to understand why this is happening or how to debug this. Any help appreciated.

[EDIT] Complete `calculate` function:

```
void calculate(struct iso_matrix *iso_matrix)
{
    printf("Calculate called\n");
    struct graphlet *graphlet = init_graphlet(GL_SIZE);
    int *index_map = (int *)malloc(iso_matrix->n_rw_col);
    struct graph *graph = init_graph(0, GL_SIZE);   /*Small graph so prefered matrix representation.*/

    /*Initialize the list_head.*/
    if(!iso_matrix->unique)
        iso_matrix->unique = init_listhead();

    for(int i=0; i<iso_matrix->n_rw_col; ++i)
    {
        graphlet_to_graph(graphlet, graph);
        calc_heuristic(graph, 3);

        /*check_unique() compares only between same type of graphs.*/
        index_map[i] = check_unique(iso_matrix->unique, graph);
        if(index_map[i]==-1)
        {
            struct graph *cpy=init_graph(0, GL_SIZE);
            cpy_graph(graph, cpy);
            int *graphlet_no = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
            *graphlet_no = i;
            struct container *container = (struct container *)malloc(sizeof(struct container));
            container->data = (void *)cpy;
            container->id = (void *)graphlet_no;
            struct list_node *list_node = init_listnode((void *)container);
            add_to_list(list_node, iso_matrix->unique);
        }
        else
        {
            *(*((iso_matrix->iso_mat)+index_map[i])+i) = 1;
        }

        inc_graphlet(graphlet);
        reset_graph(graph);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<iso_matrix->n_rw_col; ++i)
    {
        if(index_map[i]==-1)    /*If same then continue.*/
            continue;
        for(int j=0; j<iso_matrix->n_rw_col; ++j)
            *(*((iso_matrix->iso_mat)+i)+j) = *(*((iso_matrix->iso_mat)+index_map[i])+j);
    }

    /*Destroying allocated memory.*/
    free(index_map);
}
```

Comment: This is probably a buffer overrun somewhere. Memory allocation and deallocation usually detect corruption in the heap structure and issue warnings and assertions. If possible break in a debugger before the `free` and look at the memory around `index_map`. You are probably overwriting a dynamically allocated buffer in the space preceding the memory allocated for `index_map`.

Comment: It's telling you that free() got a pointer to something that doesn't look like it came from malloc(). Probably something in that "//some other stuff" section is either mucking with the pointer or overwriting memory it shouldn't. Just because the code works, that doesn't mean it's right. :-)

Comment: I checked the code, it does not look like that I am overwriting something. Can you give pointers from where I can read this form of debugging is done using GDB. I am new to GDB too. Also see the edited question.

Comment: It has been too many years since I have used GDB.  Take a look at [other questions related to _invalid next size_ errors](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=free+invalid+next+size) for some more information.  This could also occur if you free memory that was not allocated or free the same memory more than once.  Take a look at the [GDB manual as well](http://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Data.html#Data).  I vaguely remember using the "examine" or `x` command to poke around through memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm wagering that this:

```
int *index_map = (int *)malloc(iso_matrix->n_rw_col);
```

is meant to point to an allocation of `iso_matrix->n_rw_col` **integers**. You forgot the size of the integer in your byte-calculation:

```
int *index_map = malloc(iso_matrix->n_rw_col * sizeof(*index_map));
```

There are likely other issues, but this is clearly a big one. Note: I also removed the cast on `malloc()` which you should NOT be doing in C code. Ensure `stdlib.h` is included in your `#include` list at the top of this source file.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam Not without diving into the code. I never trust code I haven't thoroughly dissected, and you have a copious number of functions calls who's back-end I'll never be wise to. But this one was pretty obvious. Run it under **valgrind** to gain a little higher confidence.

Comment: @WhoCraig Okay. I thought that there are other very obvious issues. Thank you.

Comment: @AmanDeepGautam No worries. Definitely run this under valgrind. I see a lot of allocations and no matching free's for them, you may be doing that elsewhere, but this deserves a thorough memory wash to raise your confidence in that area. Anyway, glad to help.